# Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432` with aws-rds url

Tags: postgresql, docker, next.js, amazon-rds, prisma

Technologies I use:

- nextJS;
- prisma;
- postgresql;
- docker;

I'm trying to connect to the db by passing this url: `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432"`

It's an AWS RDS Postgres database and I'm sure it's working correctly because I can connect to it manually.

schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js" 
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

full error log:

```
next-1   | Failed to sync db: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgresdb
next-1   | prisma:error 
next-1   | Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
next-1   | 
next-1   | 
next-1   | Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
next-1   | 
next-1   | Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.
next-1   | ERR Error: 
next-1   | Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
next-1   | 
next-1   | 
next-1   | Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
next-1   | 
next-1   | Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.
next-1   |     at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31955:13)
next-1   |     at RequestHandler.handleAndLogRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31913:12)
next-1   |     at /app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32458:25
next-1   |     at async PrismaClient._executeRequest (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:33022:22)
next-1   |     at async PrismaClient._request (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32994:16)
next-1   |     at async Object.createUser (/app/.next/server/pages/api/graphql.js:1:15549)
next-1   |     at async Object.signup (/app/.next/server/pages/api/graphql.js:1:2170)
next-1   |     at async file:///app/node_modules/@envelop/core/esm/orchestrator.js:373:27
next-1   |     at async YogaServer.getResultForParams (file:///app/node_modules/graphql-yoga/esm/server.js:270:26)
next-1   |     at async YogaServer.getResponse (file:///app/node_modules/graphql-yoga/esm/server.js:336:23) {
next-1   |   path: [ 'signup' ],
next-1   |   locations: [ { line: 8, column: 5 } ],
next-1   |   extensions: [Object: null prototype] {}
next-1   | }
```

I tried running with these urls too:
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/postgres`

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300"
```

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/postgres?schema=public"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using: postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/postgres ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).